# Combining rows of multiple queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building a social media news aggregation web app in PHP and MySQL. It needs to map various URLs (column url) to specific trends (column trend_id). Here's my dummy data structure:

[image: Sample data]

I need to build a query to fetch URLs for a particular trend_id (for example 12). This is simple:

> SELECT `url` FROM `url_table` WHERE `trend_id` = '12'

Now, some trends are related to a specific parent trend. For example trend_ids 12,16 and 45 are related to a parent trend_id 12. So here's my query:

> SELECT '12' as `parent_trend_id`,`url` FROM `url_table` WHERE (`trend_id` = '12' OR `trend_id` = '16' OR `trend_id` = '45')

Here's another example of similar query:

> SELECT '345' as `parent_trend_id`,`url` FROM `url_table` WHERE (`trend_id` = '345' OR `trend_id` = '457' OR `trend_id` = '16')

The issue is that there are multiple such parent - child relationships between trends. As of now I run a for loop within PHP and execute multiple queries. Also, given the nature of my app the parent trend cannot be a part of this table. Is there a way to have a single query which clubs multiple such queries?

**Edit:**

I have a separate table defining <strike>child</strike> relationships. It's a simple 3 column table with ID,trend_id (parent) and related_trend_id (child). However, one related_trend_id (child) can have multiple trend_ids (parents). Here's a snapshot of the relations table:

[image: Relations table sample data]

Comment: I've updated my queries to use this table... should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You specific query would now be:

```
SELECT r.trend_id as parent_trend_id,url 
FROM url_table
Join relations r on r.related_trend_id = childid
WHERE r.trend_id = 12
```

or to get all of them

```
SELECT r.trend_id as parent_trend_id,url 
FROM url_table
Join relations r on r.related_trend_id = childid
```

Works exactly as expected for me:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b137a/9

What results did you expect?

Comment: Not working... probably as there could be multiple parents for a child. Well, is there a way to simply combine results on multiple Select statements into one... as in combine all rows as such?

Comment: I can combine the rows on sql server but I don't know how to do that on mysql -- I suggest you just do that in the client program, php is better at that kind of string manipulation.

Comment: Did just that, Used PHP to create a UNION query to combine rows into one subtable.

Answer (score 0):

Join on the table containing the parent-child relationships?

```
SELECT url_table.*
FROM url_table
INNER JOIN parents
    ON url_table.trend_id = parents.trend_id
WHERE parents.parent_id IN (1,2,3);
```

`(1,2,3)` being all the parent trends for which you want to extract tuples.

Comment: He does not have a parents table.

Comment: @Hogan I do have a table with parent child relations. Will put that up in an edit

Comment: @AkshayRaje - ROFL, that might be helpful if you want to get some good answers.

Comment: @Hogan There's a complication, there could be multiple parents. Rather its a 'related trends' table and hence a related_trend_id could be related to multiple trend_ids

Comment: @AkshayRaje it is not hard if you show us the table. Then we can help

Comment: @Hogan I have put up the relations table sample data in question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14540/discussion-between-akshay-raje-and-hogan)